# Is it legal to keep an old hole-punched driver's license or permit?

Tags: driving, oregon

It is illegal in Oregon to possess two drivers licences, but when you get a new one, the DMV hole-punches the old one and gives it back to you. The paper temporary license is valid for driving privileges but not for ID in all circumstances. The DMV employee told me they "recommend" that I destroy my instruction permit and temporary license after my permanent license arrives on the mail.

Is it legal in Oregon to keep a hole-punched driver's license or permit after it has been replaced?

Comment: If one is voting to close because a question lacks details or clarity, it might be useful for the voter to explain what they're unable to understand about the question. The question seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: I'm having no luck finding anything that says "*it is illegal in Oregon to possess two drivers licences*". Can you point me to the relevant laws, please. My guess is that it's probably illegal to possess two *currently valid* licences - especially as the DMV returned the old one and only recommend it's destruction. (Not my VTC, by the way).

Comment: If it was illegal then why do you think the DMV would hole punch it and give it back to you?

Comment: @MichaelHall the DMV employee told me to keep it until my permanent license arrives, and that they "recommend" that I destroy it when the permanent license arrives. The paper the temporary license is printed on says I "must" destroy it and the old permit.

Answer (score 5):

[ORS 807.550](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_807.550) says "A person commits the offense of holding multiple licenses if the person applies for and accepts a license or driver permit, other than an instruction driver permit, when the person holds an existing license or driver permit". There is a corresponding regulation [Driver and Motor Vehicle Services Division 735-062-0096](https://secure.sos.state.or.us/oard/viewSingleRule.action?ruleVrsnRsn=274834) elaborates, procedurally

> (1) When DMV issues an interim driver card or an interim
> identification card to an applicant under OAR 735-062-0094, DMV will
> invalidate and return the driver license, driver permit or
> identification card the applicant surrendered. An invalidated driver
> license or driver permit may not be used as proof of driving
> privileges, but is not deemed cancelled under ORS 801.175.
>
> (2) DMV will invalidate a surrendered driver license, driver permit or
> identification card by hole-punching the card.
>
> (3) The invalidated driver license, driver permit or identification
> card must be destroyed by the applicant when:
>
> (a) A valid driver license, driver permit or identification card
> issued and mailed by DMV is received by the applicant; or
>
> (b) Driving privileges or rights to an identification card have been
> suspended, cancelled or revoked.

This suggests that it is possible that your mutilated, invalidated permit is returned but you are not in possession of a replacement, for example the new license is not mailed to you at the same time as the cancelled one is mailed back. At any rate, it is not legal to keep the old cancelled one, and still have its replacement.

Comment: Thank you! What would "destroyed" mean? Would cutting it in half be sufficient? Can I keep what's left after "destroying" it?